# How can i reference windowbase dll from a different path from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I've looked around to try to find some posts on this and there are many but none that address my specific question. I am trying to add window base dll in my script but its coming from :  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.

actually i need to upload the cs file and supporting dll to the server and i don't know the path where .net framework is installed in server.

when i try to add copy windowbase.dll and upload it, i am getting following error :

The type or namespace name 'Packaging' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

please suggest some solution for this

Comment: Why do you even need to reference WindowBase.dll with a specific path? Isn't that in GAC?!?!

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** use references from c:\windows\microsoft.net.  You'll get a random outcome, depending on whether the machine has .NET 4.0 or 4.5x installed.  Lots of types where moved around in 4.5.  You *must* use the proper reference assemblies to target a .NET version, they live in c:\program files (x86)\assembly references on a 64-bit machine.  It is completely unclear why that's a problem.